# Overlapping the city dropdowns in html, css

Tags: html, css

I have 2 dropdowns, State and City. Select the State, and the particular City drop down gets visible. But all the city dropdowns are not overlapping, messing up the look. I need a way to overlap all the city dropdown's.

Below is the cut down html, what do I need to add to fix this ?

I need to add some css on this part (the city) `style="height: 30px;__something here___"`

```
<select class="input-txt" style="height: 30px;" name="Standard"
                    onchange="showDiv(this.value);">
                      <option selected="selected">
                        Select
                      </option>

                      <option value="ap-adilabad">
                        Adilabad
                      </option>
```

Cut down HTML below1

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="title">
    Need some support? Get in touch with our authorized service centers...
  </div>

  <table class="responsive-table" style=
  "width: 100%; border-width: 0; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
          <div class="fix"></div>

          <table style=
          "width: 100%; border-width: 0; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0 auto;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="responsive-td1" style="width: 39%;">
                  <h2>Select State</h2>
                </td>

                <td class="responsive-td2" style="width: 5%;"></td>

                <td>
                  <h2>Select City</h2>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td class="responsive-td3"><select class="input-txt" style=
                "height: 30px;" name="search" onchange="showS(this.selectedIndex)">
                  <option selected="selected" value="0">
                    Select
                  </option>

                  <option value="andhra">
                    Andhra Pradesh
                  </option>

                  <option value="assam">
                    Assam
                  </option>

                </td>

                <td style="width: 4%;"></td>

                <td class="responsive-td4">
                  <div id="containerSelect">
                    <select class="input-txt" style="height: 30px;" name="Select">
                      <option selected="selected">
                        Select
                      </option>
                    </select> <!--Andhra Pradesh-->
                    <select class="input-txt" style="height: 30px;" name="Standard"
                    onchange="showDiv(this.value);">
                      <option selected="selected">
                        Select
                      </option>

                      <option value="ap-adilabad">
                        Adilabad
                      </option>

                      <option value="ap-anantapur">
                        Anantapur
                      </option>
                    </select> <!--Assam-->
                    <select class="input-txt" style="height: 30px;position:absolute" name="Standard"
                    onchange="showDiv(this.value);">
                      <option selected="selected">
                        Select
                      </option>

                      <option value="as1">
                        Guwahati
                      </option>

                    </select> <!--BIHAR-->

                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>&nbsp;

          <div id="SkiDiv">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Runnable snippet is missing.

Comment: This runs on any preview based online html..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to initially have the "`display: none`" set for all the city dropdowns, then, when you select a state `showS` can set the appropriate city dropdown to "`display: inline-block`".